# How to set validation schema based on condition using Yup? Formik

Tags: react-native, formik, yup

I'm trying to use Yup to validate data in an array. For example, this is my initialValue:

```
{name:'',extra:[]}
```

After dynamic render the form field , the initialValue will become like this:

```
{name:'',extra:[{label:'age',value:'',required:true}]}
```

I want to set the validation scheme to validate the 'value' in the object only when 'required' is true.

I use this data to mock the situation:

```
{name:'john',extra:[{label:'age',value:'',required:true}]};
```

Method that i had try:

```
const validationschema = yup.object().shape({
 name: yup.string().required(),
  extra: yup.lazy((value,index)=>{
    return yup.mixed().required();
  })
})
```

There should be an error when the user submit , because the 'value' for age is empty. 
I not sure why, i can't really validate the 'value'. How do I change my validationschema so it can validate the 'value' ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to validate like:

```
name: yup.string().required(),
extra: yup.array()
  .of(
   yup.object().shape({
     required: yup.bool(),
     value: yup.object().when('required', {
       is: true,
       then: yup.string().required('Please, select position')
     }),
   })
  )
```

There you should check field `required`. If it `true` you validate it.

Comment: I got this error
 TypeError
You cannot `concat()` schema's of different types: object and string

Comment: @wkwkwk can you give sample code on sandbox or other place?